# Embedding Cocos2D-x in UIView

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

I am building an App that has nothing to do with a game. However, I have a screen that shows some views interacting with each other in a real-world way. I tried UIDynamicAnimator but it's physics engine just won't cut it.

Sprite Kit is the obvious option, however I would love to have some compatibility with android and WP8.

Therefore I went for `Cocos2D-x`. Unfortunately when I create a project it creates a whole setup for 7 platforms and a really big overhead. I just need to have an UIView which has a Cocos2d-x scene inside, so that the code I write in Cocos2d-x cpp can be latter reused in other platforms. I am looking for the simplest installation possible, currently just for iOS, without involving AppDelegate and others.

Do you think this can be achieved? Any tips will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you may want to try cocos2d-iphone instead, only 1 project and with spritebuilder android plugin (currently in beta) you can also run your cocos2d objc app on android with no extra code (besides the fact that you can't use uiview on android obviously)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried, but starting the project with spriteBuilder App (as the documentation says) makes a similar overhead. Do you know any starting project source code or how can I install Cocos2d-Iphone (which is Cocos2d-Swift now, isn't it?) in an already-started project? Thanks!

Comment: what kind of overhead do you refer to? Yes there are many targets but they are not "overhead" as such, app targets are only 3: ios, osx, android. You can remove te osx target if you like but it doesn't bloat anything if you leave it in.

Comment: Hi, have you figure it out? I have the same problem here. Thank you

Comment: hi @SonicMaster, I ended up going in another direction. Best of luck!